# Upload to database a file + folder with the same name

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, directory, special-folders

I'd like to ask something interesting to those who like difficult things in php or javascript+php, I dont mind.

I'd like to know a nice way or get some orientation of how to upload a file to a database (that's super easy) but at the same time the program has to find and upload to the same database a full folder in the same level.

It's easy to understand: filename + filename_folder.

The user just hasto find the filename in the uploader brower and that's it, the program will do the rest.

thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: Even after reading the full question more than once, I don't know what you want...

Comment: So if I upload a file called `image.png`, I'd also have to upload a folder called `image` that's from the same directory as that image?

Comment: You would have to use a script that has access to the client file system.  Why are you even trying to do this?

Comment: You could try using HTML5 FileSystem APIs http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ ...

Comment: Ok, to let you understand better, what I want is upload a COLLADA file ".dae", as you know collada comes with a package of textures that is hold in a folder that 100% of the times is calles "colladafile_folder", so, what I want is to upload that folder without any interaction of the user, is there any way?